# nginx: 502 Bad gateway error during site redirect

Tags: regex, nginx, amazon-ec2, http-redirect

I am new to Nginx and was trying to use nginx and thin.

I have tried out many sites and blogs but it is not helping.I am currently following the blog
http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/27/ubuntu-hardy-nginx-rails-and-thin

I am however getting an 502 Bad gateway error.

The below is the code I have implemented .

nginx conf file:-

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

 }

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

nginx default file(/etc/nginx/site-available):-

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        server_name  192.168.1.238:8080;


    root /home/woi/Development/public;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    # server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
        # For example, return an error code
        #return 418;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
#   ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#   }
#}
```

nginx domain.com file(/etc/nginx/sites-available):-

```
upstream domain1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
        server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    }




server {
            listen   80;
            server_name 192.168.1.238;

        #    access_log /home/demo/public_html/railsapp/log/access.log;
        #    error_log /home/demo/public_html/railsapp/log/error.log;

            root   /home/woi/Development/public/;
            index  index.html;

            location / {
                          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                          proxy_redirect off;

                          if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                                           rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                          }

                          if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                                           rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                          }

                          if (!-f $request_filename) {
                                           proxy_pass http://domain1;
                                           break;
                          }
            }

}
```

After putting `services nginx start` command,I am not able to run thin server.I am getting 502 bad gateway error when i hit my ip address 192.168.1.238.

Update:-The below is the snippet of my error log:-

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://domain1/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://domain1/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:14:18 [error] 2029#0: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://domain1/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:16:24 [error] 2171#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:16:24 [error] 2171#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:16:24 [error] 2171#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:20:04 [error] 2354#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:20:04 [error] 2354#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:20:04 [error] 2354#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/", host: "192.168.1.238"
2014/01/30 05:20:09 [error] 2354#0: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.142, server: 192.168.1.238, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://domain1/", host: "192.168.1.238"
```

The above solution is not helping me.Can someone please help me.
Am stuck for a long time now.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get in your logs?

Comment: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream... "http://127.0.0.1:3002/" IT'S ALMOST LIKE NGINX CAN'T CONNECT TO THE UPSTREAM TO SERVE THE REQUEST.

Comment: check if `localhost:3000`,`localhost:3001`,`localhost:3002` work first or not, because apparently they don't

Comment: Did you eventually solved this?

Answer (score -1):

This means that your Thin servers are not running. Try this:

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000
```

It is probably not working. Look at your Thin logs (stdout/stderr.log) to identify further problems.

Thin is a separate process and it should be restarted individually. It is common to have it setup within your Rails app in the same bundle. In that case you need to run it like:

```
bundle exec thin start
```

See: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/

If you installed your Gems as root including the thin gem, then it should have installed an init script in /etc/init.d. In that case you can restart thin with the service command.

When you deploy new code, you only need to restart your thin servers and not nginx.

Comment: if i start nginx does it mean that my thin server is starting automatically.or i have to start thin server explicitly by using command "start thin"??